# How to get average value of particular user's one column

Tags: laravel

I have a table which stores cleaning scores of different users . Now I am trying to calculate the average of that cleaning score of all users 
For example I have two users 
1. Roommie 1 
2. Roommie 2 
I want to calculate average score of each user's cleaning score

This is How I have stored score of each user

```
<?php
     public function store(Request $request)
     {
        $email = User::where('id',$request->user_id)->value('email');
        $score = CleaningScore::create([
           'score'=>$request->score,
           'user_id'=>$request->user_id,
           'giver_id'=>\Auth::user()->id
        ]);
        // \Mail::to($email)->send(new ScoreNotification($score));
           return redirect()->to('/scores/list_of_rommies/index')- 
           >with('success','Scores are successfully Assign to The 
             Rommie');
       }
 ?>
```

Now I want to calcuate average of that score of each employee 
How do I get that ???

I have tried doing this

```
$scores = Score::all();
foreach($scores as $score)
{
    $cleaning = $score->score;
    $average = $cleaning->avg();
}
```

Like this But failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try grouping users and get average of the group:

Code looks like:

```
$data = DB::table('cleaning_scores')
    ->select(DB::raw('avg(score) as avg, user_id'))
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->orderByDesc('avg')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It works thank you so much . One more question If I want to order data according to its average score What should I do 
I want to order data according to higher average score . 
User with the higer score should be on top

Comment: I've edited the answer to order score. Please mark as accepted answer with check under the counter.

Comment: Okk . Can we do it through eloquent so that I can use relationships ???

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get average from a model

```
$scoresAvg = YourModel::avg('ColumnName');
```

hope it helps

Comment: I want to get different average scores of different users not altogether . is there any idea for that